# Chapter Number replaced by chapter name

Tags: titlesec

I would like to have this style
[image]
instead of
[image]

How would one achieve this? I am using `\usepackage[md,sc]{titlesec}` to make the section titles small-caps style.

EDIT: "I" in my first picture is "1" written in this particular way (probably some non-standard font?).
And the `md, sc` options do exist in `titlesec`:
[image]

Comment: The `md` or `sc` options do no exist for `titlesec`. What is the thin `I` in your first picture?  And which document class do you use?

Comment: Yes, md, sc exist as options, but not for the advanced interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes pretty close. There was no need to specify options for the `titlesec`-package:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext, color}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]%
    {\scshape\Huge}%
    {\textcolor{gray75}{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eur}\fontseries{b}\selectfont\thechapter}%
    \hspace{10pt}%
    \vrule width.5pt depth0.1ex%
    \hspace{10pt}}%
    {0pt}%
    {\Large}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\Blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: fancy chapter]

Comment: I have also added `\titlespacing{\section}{-6pc}{3.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex minus .1ex}`-type-of-thing, in order for the title to "hang" to the left, as in the original image.

Comment: @Ilonpilaaja, that's a great addition! Would you be alright if I added your code to my answer?

Comment: sure you can! :) Thanks.